# Calculating the difference between the first and the last value in a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, quantitative-finance

I am aggregating financial data into candle stick charts using the following query below:

This will give me a number of rows each representing a candlestick for a given market, at a given point in time.

This works fine, but I'd also like to calculate the rate-of-change for prices at different intervals (last hour, last 4 hours, last day etc)

What would be the best way to accomplish this and can it be done using window functions a like the ones I'm already using?

```
SELECT
      (exchange || ':' || pair) AS id,
      exchange,
      c.pair,
      c.high AS high,
      c.low AS low,
      c.open AS open,
      c.closing AS close,
      c.volume AS volume,
      c.opened_at,
      c.closed_at,
      86400 AS interval
    FROM (
      SELECT
        exchange,
        pair,
        FIRST_VALUE(closed_at)
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY exchange, pair, floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) / (86400))
          ORDER BY closed_at
        ) opened_at,
        LAST_VALUE(closed_at)
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY exchange, pair, floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) / (86400))
          ORDER BY closed_at
        ) closed_at,
        FIRST_VALUE(open)
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY exchange, pair, floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) / (86400))
          ORDER BY closed_at
        ) open,
        MAX(high)
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY exchange, pair, floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) / (86400))
          ORDER BY closed_at
        ) high,
        MIN(low)
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY exchange, pair, floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) / (86400))
          ORDER BY closed_at
        ) low,
        LAST_VALUE(close)
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY exchange, pair, floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) / (86400))
          ORDER BY closed_at
        ) closing,
        SUM(volume)
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY exchange, pair, floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) / (86400))
          ORDER BY closed_at
        ) volume
      FROM candles
      WHERE exchange = 'gdax' AND pair = 'ethusd' AND closed_at > '2017-10-01 10:00:00' AND volume > 0
    ) c
    WHERE EXTRACT(epoch FROM closed_at) - EXTRACT(epoch FROM opened_at) = ((86400 - (1 * 60))) 
    ORDER BY closed_at DESC
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Your query is fine.  You could simplify it by defining a window in the `from` clause and using that for all the window functions.

Comment: This question would need to include the exact table definition showing data types and constraints and your version of Postgres. Cardinalities and value frequencies for key columns. And some rationale for your time calculations. If you want to partition by *day*, there are simpler ways ... Finally, define "best" way. Performance? Short code? Clear code? SQL-standard-conforming? Fit for different time zones?